# Get Impala equivalent of MONTHS_BETWEEN() in Snowflake

Tags: datediff, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am facing a problem while migrating queries from Impala to Snowflake :

**Impala**

```sql
SELECT period
    , now() as dt_today
    , MONTHS_BETWEEN(now(), period) as mb
FROM my_table
```

yields

```
period                  dt_today                        mb
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
2018-10-30T21:43:57Z    2020-02-21 10:21:12.827383000   15.709677419354838
```

**Snowflake**

```sql
SELECT period
    , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() as dt_today
    , DATEDIFF('month', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), period) as mb
FROM my_table
```

yields

```
period                  dt_today                        mb
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
2018-10-30T21:43:57Z    2020-02-21 10:21:12.827383000   16
```

Now, from Snowflake [documentation](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/datediff.html) I understand that when specifying `month` in `DATEDIFF`, Snowflake will only "use the month and year from the date" **meaning the difference is not as accurate as Impala's.**
I've tried implementing a *proxy* like taking the month difference and then apply some calculation to get the floating point part as such but I still get a wrong number of month :

```
DATEDIFF('month', period, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) + (GREATEST(DAY(period), DAY(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())) -  LEAST(DAY(period), DAY(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()))) / 31
```

as well as the following to get even more precise but it still isn't right :

```
DATEDIFF('day', period, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())/31 + (GREATEST(DAY(period), DAY(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())) -  LEAST(DAY(period), DAY(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()))) / 31
```

Question : how can I exactly reproduce Impala's `MONTHS_BETWEEN()` in Snowflake ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR

```sql
IFF(DAY(DATE1) >= DAY(DATE2), DATEDIFF('month', DATE2, DATE1), DATEDIFF('month', DATE2, DATE1) - 1)
+
IFF(DAY(DATE1) >= DAY(DATE2), (GREATEST(DAY(DATE1), DAY(DATE2)) - LEAST(DAY(DATE1), day(DATE2))) / 31, 1 - (GREATEST(DAY(DATE1), DAY(DATE2)) - LEAST(DAY(DATE1), DAY(DATE2))) / 31)
```

---

Impala `MONTHS_BETWEEN(DATE1, DATE2)` function works as follows :

- `MONTHS_BETWEEN('2019-04-13', '2019-02-10')` yields `2.0967` (`2` full months + `3/31=0967`)
- `MONTHS_BETWEEN('2019-04-13', '2019-02-03')` yields `1.7741` (`1` full months + `1-(7/31)=0967`)

Now we know that Snowflake `DATEDIFF(DATE1, DATE3)` applies a simple month-to-month operation :

- `DATEDIFF('month', '2019-04-13', '2019-02-10')` yields `2` (`04 - 02`)
- `DATEDIFF('month', '2019-04-13', '2019-02-03')` yields `2` (`04 - 02`)

In order to get the integer part of Impala's `MONTHS_BETWEEN` using Snowflake functions we apply the following logic :

```sql
IFF(DAY(DATE1) >= DAY(DATE2), DATEDIFF('month', DATE2, DATE1), DATEDIFF('month', DATE2, DATE1) - 1)
```

In order to get the fractional part of Impala's `MONTHS_BETWEEN` using Snowflake functions we apply the following logic :

```sql
IFF(DAY(DATE1) >= DAY(DATE2), (GREATEST(DAY(DATE1), DAY(DATE2)) - LEAST(DAY(DATE1), day(DATE2))) / 31, 1 - (GREATEST(DAY(DATE1), DAY(DATE2)) - LEAST(DAY(DATE1), DAY(DATE2))) / 31)
```

We simply add them together to get Impala's exact value :

```sql
IFF(DAY(DATE1) >= DAY(DATE2), DATEDIFF('month', DATE2, DATE1), DATEDIFF('month', DATE2, DATE1) - 1)
+
IFF(DAY(DATE1) >= DAY(DATE2), (GREATEST(DAY(DATE1), DAY(DATE2)) - LEAST(DAY(DATE1), day(DATE2))) / 31, 1 - (GREATEST(DAY(DATE1), DAY(DATE2)) - LEAST(DAY(DATE1), DAY(DATE2))) / 31)
```

Answer (score 0):

How precise does your difference need to be?

Because my first call would be to substract both dates (getting the difference in days) - or you can just use datediff just extracting the day - and go from there (either by dividing by 30/31 if approximation would do or with some more complex calc if I need exact solution)

Your solution is not right because the months in datediff are going to differ by 1 even on the subsequent days if you take let's say 31st of dec and 1st of jan - those 2 would give "1" in datediff both by year, month and day.

Comment: I've edited my answer with another proxy I've tried however I need the exact precision and this is close but not exact !

Comment: Hm, in that case I'd consider sth like "check for full number of months, use add_months to add them, check how many days you still need to add and use that to get the decimal part"?

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake natively supports it: [4.42 Release Notes](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/4-42-Release-Notes-December-15-17-2020).

> [MONTHS_BETWEEN](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/months_between.html)
>
> ```
> MONTHS_BETWEEN( <date_expr1> , <date_expr2> )
> ```
>
> Returns the number of months between two DATE or TIMESTAMP values.